# Program to take photos with webcam in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webcam

I need a program for Ubuntu 14.04 that will allow me to take photos with a laptop's built-in webcam.

Required features:

- Preview the webcam on-screen before taking the photo.
- Must be available either in the Ubuntu Software Center or via apt-get without adding repositories.
- Save pictures in common image formats (jpg and png at a minimum).

Unwanted features:

- Image editing capabilities. I have more than enough software capable of doing image editing/processing, and this would likely only make the program unnecessarily larger than I need.
- Silent capture mode. I want to know that the webcam is being accessed while the program is running.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to have the linux tag?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs I don't have an actual problem with adding the linux tag, but I don't see enough reason for it to be added when my question already specified Ubuntu (a much more specific subset of the linux tag). I am against the change of wording in the question as "not required" and "unwanted features" have slightly different meanings. I am also against removing the Ubuntu tag (as had happened) since my question specifically is about Ubuntu.

Comment: RE: Ubuntu: Did you read [this meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1111/94)? - RE: "unwanted": As you wish.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Yes I did read that after I made the above comment, and that is why I have kept the linux tag, as well as re-adding the ubuntu tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably looking for **[Cheese](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Cheese)** (see also [its Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese_%28software%29)), which can be used to make photos or videos using your webcam. Once started, Cheese...

- constantly displays what the webcam "sees" (aka "preview")
- offers you a few buttons to select the mode (photo, video)
- saves pictures in standard formats (videos use `.ogv` Ogg Vorbis files)

*Cheese* is available via the standard Ubuntu repositories. Additional to your requirements, the software also features...

- sharing pictures
- configuring the resolution (if the webcam supports that)
- taking pictures in "burst mode" (i.e. "picture series")
- switch between multiple webcams (in case you have them)
- some effect overlays (sorry, I know you don't want those "extras" – but there they are; the screenshot to the right shows one in use)
- timer (countdown to take picture)

[image: Cheese] [image: Cheese]
<sup>*Cheese* (source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese_%28software%29), [UbuntuUsers](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Cheese); click images for larger variants)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with *any* video player that supports `ffmpeg`'s `libavdevice` library, or `video4linux` directly, and have ability to take screenshots, in general. Or even `ffmpeg`'s `ffplay` itself. Let's take a look at using awesome [mpv](https://mpv.io) for this.

First, you need to determine which device path corresponds to your webcam:

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
<...>
        /dev/video0
```

Remember this path. Second, *play* this input in video player:

```
$ mpv av://v4l2:/dev/video0
```

When you want to "take photo", just do screenshot (defaults to `s` in `mpv`). Done!

For more details about how to specify correct input URI, see [docs](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#protocols), particularly section about `av://` URIs. For other players see corresponding docs.

Note that such approach let's you involve full power of players: you can apply any desired filters, process, post-process output, record video instead of just taking "photos" - anything you can imagine!